# require 'geoip' causes an error on Ruby 1.8

Tags: ruby, rubygems, geoip

I've installed the pure ruby gem from maxmind.com following these directions http://geoip.rubyforge.org/.

Unfortunately

```
require 'geoip'
```

causes the following error:

```
`require': no such file to load -- geoip (LoadError)
```

I've checked my system and found geoip installed in the following locations:

```
/usr/local/bin/geoip
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/geoip-1.2.1/bin/geoip
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/geoip-1.2.1/data/geoip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Ruby 1.8 you have to explicitly require `rubygems` before `geoip`:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'geoip'
```